# WAMP server stalling when trying to run mysql test file

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have just installed WAMP server, using Port 81, on a Windows 64 bit machine.  It runs and I can open the index.php file with it.  However, when I try to open the testmysql.php file, it appears to kill the server.

After trying to run testmysql.php, which never loads, I get the same problem with the index.php file - it will not load either.  I can then get the index.php file to load only by restarting all services on WAMP server.

I have Avira running on the computer, but it doesn't seem to be causing a problem.  With it running, I can load and refresh index.php as many times as I want.  It appears that the problem is always created by trying to run the testmysql.php file.

The code for the testmysql.php file is as follows:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost:81','root','');
if (!$link) { 
   die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connection OK'; mysql_close($link); 
?>
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: In the WAMP GUI Control Panel, is MySQL green/started?

Comment: Port 81 is for the apache service not for the sql. Change to this `mysql_connect('localhost','root','');`. Also mysql_ is now deprecated, use pdo/mysqli

Comment: Thanks!  I had added the ":81" because it wasn't working without it, but now, by deleting it, the code works.  I'm not sure what was wrong before, but it is working now.  Thank you.